# Realtime data-streaming from server with nodejs + RxJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, real-time, rxjs

I've just created an API(in NodeJs) to create user and calling that API from a mobile app. Now I want to display that user to user list table in Web(Without refreshing or AJAX call). Socket.io might can do that, but I've already used RxJS. Is there any way to do this stuff using RxJs?